# Regex to match currency with or without thousands seperator java

Tags: java, regex, string

I want to match currency with or without any thousand separators and or decimals.

String example

```
String part =  "R4,491.25"; // must be able to match more ex : R12,550,000.60
```

What i have

```
if( part.matches("\\R\\d*[.,\\s\\d*]+")){
   System.out.println("C [" + part + "]");
}
```

Found this [Regex for number with decimals and thousand separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148034/regex-for-number-with-decimals-and-thousand-separator) and [Python regex to match currency with or without comma or decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143814/python-regex-to-match-currency-with-or-without-comma-or-decimal)

But neither accomplishes what i need . in Javascrpt using regex101 my example seems to work https://regex101.com/r/rK2jMU/4

How can i improve or change my regex to allow for the requirements as stated above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should remove the escape backslash before `R`.

Comment: Could you put it in an answer so i can accept it please. Thanks it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches a line break (`\R` matches a line break in Java 8 regex) as the first symbol.

So, the fix will look like

```
part.matches("R\\d*[.,\\s\\d*]+")
```

You might want to try another, more precise regex (that will not allow empty whole number part though):

```
"R(?:\\d{1,3}(?:[\\s,]\\d{3})+|\\d+)(?:\\.\\d+)?"
```

Here is [this regex demo fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/TIrI23/1)

Comment: Great will use your precise one. ^R(?:\\d{1,3}(?:[\\s,]\\d{3})+|\\d+)(?:\\.\\d+)?$

Comment: Note that with `String.matches`, you do not need to add `^` and `$` as the pattern is anchored by default (= full string match is expected).

Comment: Will amend it like that. Did not know that. :) thanks